# git how to find new directories in local folder

Tags: git

If I add a new folder inside a cloned repository I can't see them with `git status`. Git reports only for new files in already known directories.

Any chance to find directories added inside a repository path?

I know that directories itself are not tracked in git. But I want to find new content within new directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is content within a new directory, then git will tell you about the directory, as long as the path is not ignored.

```
$ ls new_dir
a.txt b.txt

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    new_dir/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: forget about. I have only files in that dir which are part of .gitignore :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a repo and add a new directory, git won't acknowledge it because - as you pointed out - it won't track the directory so there's nothing it cares about.

If you put one or more files in/under that directory, then the directory should be listed in the "untracked" section of `git status`.  As far as I know git will not list the individual files until it has some tracking under the directory.

You could of course use non-git commands to see what's in the directory(ies) that git shows as untracked.  For example if git says that `some_dir` is untracked, you could do `find some_dir -type f` to see what (untracked) files exist under `some_dir`